# Why does GitHub needs **only** the public key to work with ssh?

Tags: encryption, ssh

I visited [Whose key is used to encrypt a HTTPS response?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23318485/whose-key-is-used-to-encrypt-a-https-response).

I came to know that a public key encrypts data and a private key decrypts that data.

It makes sense when I think that GitHub needs the public key to encrypt code in the repo when I try to pull that code from that repo.

But what about `push`? I have the public key to encrypt my data (that i want to `push` to my repository)....but GitHub doesn't have the private key to decrypt my pushed data. But still...GitHub `push` works using ssh...

**So my question is:** Why GitHub doesn't need my private key to decrypt my data that I push to my GitHub repo?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is here [Already Answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479567/why-does-github-only-need-my-public-key-in-order-to-push#:~:text=The%20general%20idea%20in%20a,t%20need%20your%20private%20key.)

Comment: Thanks @PankajYadav I have flagged the post.

Comment: @PankajYadav One out-of-the-topic question... Your `:~:text=` syntax on the URL doesnt seem to focus to that post that you tried to focus. I also tried the same many times...seems like `:~:text=` doesnt work sometimes. Do you know what is this `:~:text=` called?

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by @PankajYadav

ref: [Why Does GitHub only need my public key in order to push?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28479567/why-does-github-only-need-my-public-key-in-order-to-push#28479695)

GitHub is not at all interested in sending/receiving **encrypted** data. GitHub just wants to authenticate the user using the public key that the user provided to GitHub.